# .Net Core, Dapper e Visual Studio Code?

Tags: asp.net-core, dapper, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando integrar o Dapper ao .Net Core, mas não estou conseguindo e todos os tutoriais que achei, eram feitos no Visual Studio, usando o Nugget. Então alguém saberia me explicar como fazer a importação do Dapper através do Visual Studio Code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Para instalar o [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/) ou qualquer pacote é só utilizar a parte destinada a `NETCLI`, como demostrada na imagem abaixo:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e quando estiver com o [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) aberto, vai em ***terminal*** e digite o que está descrito no `NETCLI` do [NUGET](https://www.nuget.org), e pressione <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, ***exemplo***:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no final da instalação terá uma resposta em seu terminal assim:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sub>***Dica:***</sub>

No final de qualquer instalação só para ratificar **digite**:

> [`dotnet restore`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore)

***Referencias***

- [Dapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Dapper/)
- [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)
- [dotnet-restore](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore)